# Proxy server with Node.js on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, proxy

I'm trying to build a proxy server on with Node.js on Heroku using http-proxy. 
Everything works fine locally, but I'm having some troubles on Heroku.

```
var http = require('http');
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

settings = {
  "localhost": process.env.LOCALHOST,
  "devices":   process.env.DEVICES_URI
}

var options = { router: { } }
options.router[settings.localhost + '/devices']  = settings.devices + '/devices';

var port   = process.env.PORT || 8000;
var server = httpProxy.createServer(options).listen(port);
```

As you can see the in the example I set a routing object. What I say is this: 
when a request matches '/devices' then route the request to the the device service.
(identified by the DEVICES_URI environmental var)

In development I set

- LOCALHOST = 'localhost'
- DEVICES_URI = 'http://localhost:3000'

This means that all requests going to localhost:8000/devices are proxied to
localhost:3000/devices which is what I want. All works perfectly.

The problem is in production. It gives me a timeout error repeated multiple times
for every request.

```
2012-08-23T20:18:20+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> GET lelylan-api.herokuapp.com/devices dyno=web.1 queue= wait= service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
```

In the production the environment vars are configured to the app names.

- LOCALHOST = 'lelylan-api.herokuapp.com'
- DEVICES_URI = 'lelylan-devices.herokuapp.com/'

I guess I'm wrong is some configurations, but after the whole day I'm still 
not able to figure it out.

**Update**

I've continued with my tests and I've seen that the proxy is not able to reach the proxied service which totally stops me.

In development I set:

- LOCALHOST = 'localhost'
- DEVICES_URI = 'lelylan-devices.herokuapp.com/'

If I call http://lelylan-devices.herokuapp.com/devices everything works fine.

If I call localhost:8000/devices (which points to http://lelylan-devices.herokuapp.com/devices) Heroku tells me there is no such an app. I guess the problem is somehow in the routing system.

Here you can access at the [source code](https://github.com/lelylan/api/).
Here the configuration vars for Heroku.

```
NODE_ENV      => production
LOCALHOST     => lelylan-api.herokuapp.com
DEVICES_URI   => lelylan-devices.herokuapp.com
TYPES_URI     => lelylan-types.herokuapp.com
LOCATIONS_URI => lelylan-locations.herokuapp.com
```

Comment: Is the `,` in your `settings` object in the correct place?

Comment: Typo on simplifying the code for the post. You can see the complete file [here](https://github.com/lelylan/api/blob/master/web.js) (a bit messy, but i'm in full development).

Answer (score 5):

I finally made it work using a slightly modified version [proxy-by-url](https://github.com/dominictarr/proxy-by-url). The final code looks something like this and works fine.

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

var routing = {
  '/devices': { port: process.env.DEVICES_PORT || 80, host: process.env.DEVICES_URI }
}

var server = httpProxy.createServer(
  require('./lib/uri-middleware')(routing)
).listen(port);
```

One note to remember. The plugin sets the header HOST to the destination application uri. If you do not do so, Heroku will not recognize the app and will not find it, as its internal routing system seems to be based on the HOST header.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. I had used proxy-by-url in the past but forgot to mention it. Sorry about that.

Comment: Don't joke. The comments you gave me was really useful, and actually, I think the route table could just work setting the correct host header. Anyway, the url rooting seems way more cleaner. Thanks one more time.

Answer (score 2):

I use http-proxy successfully on Heroku. The first thing I noticed in your log err is the url it is GETting:
GET lelylan-api.herokuapp.com/tdevices

There is a typo... instead of '/devices' it shows '/tdevices'. Before continuing can you confirm this is the actual log message?

Comment: It was a typo, thanks for noticing it. I re-run the request and the 't' is not present. I've updated the message with the correct one. I've also opened up the [repository](https://github.com/lelylan/api/) to better check the code. I'm happy to hear it's something wrong about me. +1

Comment: One thing: be sure the target url is just the {hostname}/{path} and do not include the protocol bits (http://). I think I recall this causing me an issue on the routing with the lib before. If you do any POST's be sure to read the caveats in the docs on the github page too.

Comment: I've tried to set the target url without protocol. 
Before it was http://lelylan-devices.herokuapp.com/, now it is lelylan-devices.herokuapp.com/. I still get the same error. About POSTing I'm not using express, so everything should run smoothy. Thanks for your time. Did you check the source code?

Comment: No problem. I did look it over. I have just used the RoutingProxy with the lib and not the routing tables.Perhaps there is a bug in the routing table as you suggested. However I do want to point out that your Heroku environment variables _do_ have the protocol in them...I know you said you tried without but just asserting it again...

Comment: You right to assert it once more. To be sure, I updated the environment variables in the original questions.

Comment: I've also removed the final '/' from the Heroku environment variables. Still nothing to do and no way to log any message.

Comment: Perhaps you can try to use the proxyRequest call on a single target url to test it. I haven't tried to setup the localhost as just another proxy in the proxy table and I can't see where you starting your /api server even though you `require` http. Maybe tease out that as a server and try to go the route proxy instead?

Comment: Thanks. Tomorrow I'll try to test a single target and I'll start also to dig in the source code. One more question. Do you know if using proxyRequest you always have to set host and port, or is there a way to set just a uri?

Comment: I believe it throws if you don't set the port.

Comment: I finally managed to make it work. I used a middleware. I'm facing other problems not, but it proxy all GETs and I'll be testing the other requests verbs soon. Thanks for your help.